# Floor function not behaving the way I expect inside a For loop

Tags: iterators

When I execute the following code

```
y = Ceiling[π, 0.001]
3.142

For[i = 0, i <= 10, i = i + 0.001,
  If[Floor[i/y] == 1,
    Print[i];
    Print[i - 0.001, " ", Floor[(i - 0.001)/y]];
    Break[];
  ];
];
```

I get this result.

```
3.143
3.142 0
```

`y` is equal to `3.142`, so why is this code not ending when `i = 3.142`? If I do a similar operation outside of a `For` loop, it works as expected. When I try it with `i-0.001` outside of the `For` loop, it still doesn't work. I know it has to do something with the iterator variable.

```
Floor[3.142/y] (*This is what I expect. i should be 3.142 at the end of the For loop*)
1 

i - 0.001
3.142

Floor[(i - 0.001)/y] (*I think this should give the same result as Floor[3.142/y]*)
0
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You are expecting infinite precision results from machine precision calculations. The result of adding `0.001` 3142 times is a tiny bit less than `3.142` due to rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the sad fact that machine floating point always has precision issues. Summing a lot of little numbers is often a good way to lose precision. This seems to apply to your code.

Multiplication by integers is usually more accurate than summing. When I switch from summing to multiplying by .001, I get

```
y = Ceiling[π, 0.001]
```

> `3.142`

```
For[k = 1; i = 0., k <= 4000, ++k,
  If[Floor[i/y] == 1., 
    Print["i = ", i, "  k = ", k]; Break[], 
    i = .001 k]]
```

> `i = 3.142  k = 3143`

Which is what you expected.